# MongoDb connection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a separate file for the MongoDB connection and exported the mongoose instance

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const db = mongoose.connection;

const databaseOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    keepAlive: true,
    poolSize: 10,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL + process.env.DATABASE_NAME, databaseOptions)

db
.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Database successfully connected.")
})
.on("error", () => {
    console.log("Error in connecting database.")
})
.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Database disconnected.")
})

module.exports = mongoose
```

Now In my model
Either I import database connection file (which exports mongoose instance)

> const mongoose = require('../database-connection');

or I directly write

> const mongoose = require("mongoose")

1. How is the mongoose is able to perform connection as I have created separate mongoose
2. What is the difference between these two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the lines you provided will allow Mongoose to perform the database connection, but they are used in slightly different contexts. Let's break down the difference:

Using a Separate Database Connection File:
When you create a separate file for the database connection, like the database-connection.js file you've shown, it exports the mongoose instance after setting up the connection parameters. This approach is useful when you want to centralize your database configuration and keep your codebase organized. By importing this file in your model files, you ensure that the connection setup is consistent across your application.

Directly Using Mongoose:
When you use const mongoose = require("mongoose") directly in your model files, you are relying on Mongoose's default behavior to connect to a MongoDB instance. This works because Mongoose internally maintains a single connection instance, and calling mongoose.connect() multiple times does not create additional connections; it reuses the existing one. If you're only working with one database instance in your application, using require("mongoose") directly can simplify your code.

So, both approaches will establish a connection to the MongoDB instance. The main difference is that using a separate file for database connection configuration can help centralize and manage your connection settings more effectively, especially in larger applications where consistency and organization are important. On the other hand, directly using require("mongoose") is more straightforward and simpler in cases where you're dealing with a single database connection.